# How to make a function like swirl() in R?

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I was interested in generating a course like "swirl" in R. So a course that would interact with the user upon running it. I wanted to start from scratch and I am not sure on how to do this. Is there any specific documentation for this technique or does it have a specific name I could look for?

Comment: Why not just use swirl?: https://swirlstats.com/instructors.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [learnr](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/) with [rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)?
With learnr you can create rmarkdown docs that can run code, show results, preserve code and results.